# Create a Fiscal Year table

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I just created a fiscal_year table contents

```
- Week  (tinyint 1-53)
- Start date (date)
- End date (date)
- Year (int)
```

I would like to make a SP to insert dates into this table with parameters:

```
- Year: <2013>
- Start Year date: <12/30/2012>
- End Year date: <12/28/2013>
```

Then it will generate 52 weeks accordingly to the below in the table:

```
- Week: 1
- Start date: 12/30/2012
- End date: 01/05/2013
- Year 2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DECLARE @d DATE = '20121230';

;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT TOP (53) n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1
    FROM sys.all_objects 
    ORDER BY [object_id]
)
--INSERT dbo.fiscal_year([week],[start date],[end date],[year])
SELECT 
  [week] = n+1, 
  [start date] = DATEADD(WEEK, n, @d), 
  [end date] = DATEADD(DAY, n*7+6,@d), 
  [year] = 2013
FROM x
ORDER BY n;
```

When you're happy with the output, uncomment the `INSERT`.

Comment: @Aaon Bertrand, I keep getting: "Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date". Do you know what is the conflict here?

Comment: @tkvo well, did you change the code I provided in any way? Sounds like either you changed the code or the error is happening somewhere else...

Comment: @Aaon Bertrand, I added /@y VACHAR(4), and at the line changed to [year] = /@y. Is it because my variable types?

Comment: I don't know what you've done. Can you tell me what your output needs to be; why is year now a varchar(4) when in the question you wanted an int? Are you changing the requirements? Why? And I still don't know exactly what you've changed but don't understand how changing the [year] line could lead to the error you're reporting. Unfortunately it is tough to describe code changes in a comment.

Comment: sorry... year should be int. The output would like to be: Row1-->[week]=1, [start_date]=12/30/2012, [end_date]=01/05/2013, [year]=2013; Row2--> [week]=2, [start_date]=01/06/2012, [end_date]=01/12/2013,[year]=2013; so on...

Comment: Yes, and the code sample in my answer does exactly what you've asked for. How you've changed it and why you're getting the error you're getting, I have absolutely no idea, so I think you're on your own to sort that out (I am leaving the building to catch a plane). Start with what I have and then explain why it isn't producing what you need, and perhaps I can revisit this later.

Comment: how could I fix the issue if February has 29 days?

Comment: @tkvo what issue when February has 29 days? All of the weeks still have 7 days, right? What's the issue?

Comment: @Aaon Bertrand for some reason, when I ran 2016 Year, February missing the 29th day.

Comment: @Aaon Bertrand nvm, I re-done everything from scratch and all worked out now, not sure what was the issue. Thanks a lot for all your help!